# The button is not scrolling up when the keyboard pop up

Tags: android

The button is not scrolling up when the keyboard pops up. 
I have tried this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize".
```

I think the problem is with the XML. When we click on the edit text the keyboard pops up, and I expect the button should come above the key board. Please help me looking in to the XML code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/min_dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/min_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/min_dp"
                android:keepScreenOn="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_align_splash" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/min_dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/min_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_xl1"
                android:text="@string/title_enter_email"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                style="@style/EditInput"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_s1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                style="@style/Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/min_dp"
                android:text="@string/title_button_next" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:elevation="@dimen/size_s1"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_align_splash" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            layout="@layout/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your button and ScrollView under same parent layout. 
E.g:

```
<RelativeLayout>
      <ScrollView...../>
      <Button/>
<RelativeLayout/>
```